# Firebase installation for IOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

A final year software engineering student, I felt like building an iPhone application that manages the weekly shopping list at the supermarket.
I installed xcode on a new macOS sonoma OS.
The application works fine on the iPhone, but at the moment I don't have a database that manages it and allows it to work with all the IOS devices of my family members.
Therefore I decided to download firebase my program, I worked together with GPT in order to install it properly but I encountered 20 errors:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxK6z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usrRq.png)

I tried several steps to solve the problem.

1. I deleted and updated cocoapods.
2. I updated the Podfile
3. I removed warnings during the installation phase for the tests folders with $(inherited)
4. I turned the computer off and on, closed and opened xcode
5. I deleted the construction of the project using the command:
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivadData
   I rebuilt using the command:
   open 'project_name.xcworkspace'

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use cocoapods any more. Add firebase using Swift package manager.